# How to configure SharePoint for use with UAG?

Tags: 2013, alternate-access-mapping, https

We have a SharePoint 2013 that we use internally. For these sites we use a domain, let's call it ***http://intranet.example.com/***. Now we want to make some websites available for external users using UAG and want to use the same domain ***https://intranet.example.com/***.

We don't want to deal with certificates and terminate the ssl on UAG.

When we access the site with the url https://intranet.example.com/ over UAG, SharePoint shows the pages with http links (not https). How do I get SharePoint to show all links (JavaScript includes) with https so they are loaded by the browsers?

Answer (score 1):

You need to [configure Alternate Access Mappings to work with UAG](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261814%28v=office.12%29.aspx). Pay special attention to the section about publishing with a reverse proxy.

It should look like this:

```
Internal URL                Zone         Public URL

http://portal.company.com   Internet     https://portal.company.com
```

The easiest way to understand these that I have read is this:

> **Left area**:            Internal URL’s 
> **Right area**:          Public URL’s
>   with a zone
>  **Middle area**:        Zones, is what connects Internal URL’s
>   to Public URL’s, many to one.
>
> **Internal URL** redirects or transforms to a Public URL, from left, to
>   right. The URL on the left, is what you enter in the address field in
>   your browser, the Public URL on the right is what you will see once
>   there, this goes for visible and invisible links as well. Internal URL
>   format: Protocol + URL (+non default port)
>
> **Public URL** is the address of the Web Application for one of the five
>   zones available. The ‘Default’ must be filled out and has some special
>   properties/uses, the other four are optional. You can only have five
>   Public URL’s per Web Application. This is the URL that the browser
>   will be redirected to in the end. Public URL format: Protocol + URL
>   (+non default port)
>
> **Zone** is a label representing a Public URL, the zone is used to
>   ‘connect’ an Internal URL to a Public URL. The zone names has no
>   relation what so ever with the four Internet Explorer security zones
>   (Internet, Local Intranet, Trusted sites and Restricted sites) and
>   could just as easily been named 1,2,3,4 and 5. A zone can also
>   represent an authentication provider. Zones: Default, Intranet,
>   Internet, Custom, Extranet

[From Thomas Balkeståhl's blog.](http://blog.blksthl.com/2012/12/03/a-guide-to-alternate-access-mappings-basics-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: OK, today I have only `http://portal.company.com   Default      http://portal.company.com` and I'm unable to add `https://portal.company.com`

Comment: ... the error message says that the url is already there

Comment: Could you show a few screenshots of what you are doing up to and including when you get the error?

Comment: I finally managed to configure AAM as you suggested. But I wasn't able to use both http for internal and https for externals users. So I'm using https now for internal access and external access via uag.